# What type of duck is this? Seen in south-east London park

Tags: bird-identification, ducks

Can anyone help ID this bird? It was surprisingly large (bigger than a mallard) and seen in a park in south-east London. Initially thought wigeon or pochard but the breast colour doesn't seem to be right for either of those.

[image: blurry duck]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not a duck but a small species of goose, [Egyptian goose](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_goose). They're not native to the UK, but have been introduced and feral birds are not uncommon.

The head can appear darker in contrast to the breast in sub-adult birds; see the gallery at the Wikipedia link above.

They're not always in books as (apart from very rare vagrants) they're feral descendents of introduced birds

Comment: We have them in California, too.

Comment: Called a "goose", but is probably in a group that includes "shelducks", that contains birds that evolved a duck-like shape independently of the dabbling or of the diving ducks. "Duck" "Swan" and "Goose" are fairly vaguely defined.

Comment: @JamesK shelducks are or were sometimes called sheldgeese, a term that also applies to related species. The anatidae (swans, geese, and ducks) are a big family, but I'm no expert on the more detailed taxonomy. Egyptian goose is the only living species in the genus Alopochen, but as you say shares a subfamily ([tadorninae](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tadorninae)) with the shelducks.

Comment: They used to be very rare in most of Europe but are now more and more often getting to be a pest, very common and displacing the more welcome geese.